# Downgrade XDocument and XmlReader to XmlDocument and XmlReader

Tags: c#, compact-framework, linq-to-xml, downgrade

I want to downgrade a **Windows Mobile** application made with **.Net Compact Framework 3.5** to **.Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2**.

But... I don't know how to make this piece of code compatible with version 2.0.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(string.Format(Open_Cell_Id_Uri, new object[]{
    Settings.OpenCellIDApiKey,
    towerDetails.MobileCountryCode, 
    towerDetails.MobileNetworkCode, 
    towerDetails.TowerId,
    towerDetails.LocationAreaCode
    }));

using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader())
{
     ...
}
```

I changed using System.Xml.Linq with using System.Xml but this line is complaining:

```
using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader())
```

How can I obtain a XmlReader from a XmlDocument?

This is the code that I've downgraded:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(string.Format(Open_Cell_Id_Uri, new object[]{
    Settings.OpenCellIDApiKey,
    towerDetails.MobileCountryCode, 
    towerDetails.MobileNetworkCode, 
    towerDetails.TowerId,
    towerDetails.LocationAreaCode
    }));

using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = doc.CreateReader())//;
{
    ...
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a node reader:

```
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement)) {...}
```